# Monitor and set an alert for Invalid file names

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript

I want to monitor the particular Folder where people are placing the excel sheets for some activities.

I want to make sure that people should take care of the below rules before placing the excel sheets.

1. The excel sheet should be in xls format (Excel 97-2003 Workboomk Format)
2. The excel file name should not contain any space
3. The length of the file name should not exceed 15 characters.

I want to set a email alert to me if the users placed a excel sheet without following the above 3 rules.

I need a VB or Powershell script or batch to monitor the folder. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Have a look at numerous articles here about FileSystemWatcher in powershell. You can just look for everything in a specific folder and then write a function that contains your validation rules. I will be happy to post a more detailed example if necessary. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am pretty new to the scripting things. Can post an example. So that I can build my script from your example.

Comment: Let's say you have there a `sheet1.xls`, but inside there's an executable. Do you need to query this condition?

Comment: @Vesper, No, Users only place excel sheets. I need the excel should be in xls format, but some user wrongly placing the excel sheet in xlsx format. There is job in the backend which consumes excel sheets only if it is in xls format. So job will not run if there is any excel sheet with wrong format, have spaces in the name and the length of the excel sheet name exceeds some specific limit. People are placing some 1000 of excels sheet and i cant monitor manually each one of them if the job didint run

Comment: You might probably get more with [File Screening](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732074.aspx) than by writing custom code. This way users will quickly adapt to the rules enforced.

Comment: @Vesper File screening can be used only in the servers and I dont have administrator access to enable File screening Management.. My Folder is in the NAS location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like two steps.  Step 1, write a section of code that can be run to check files for the correct conditions.  Step 2, email users the list of incorrectly named files.  Step 1 is fairly simple.

```
Dim fso, scanFolder, files, n, fileList, fileArray
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set scanFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Your\Folder\Here")
Set files = scanFolder.Files
fileList = ""

for each n in files
    if len(n.name) > 15 or right(n.name, 3) <> "xls" or InStr(n.name, " ") > 0 then
        fileList = fileList & n.name & "|"
    end if
next

fileList = left(fileList, len(fileList) - 1)
fileArray = split(fileList, "|")
```

This will grab a list of all inappropriately named files.

Step 2.  Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no way for an FSO to get the owner name out of file.  Best you can do is email a distribution list with the list of files named in error.  I hope this helps.

Edit:  this is the email code I use in my scripts.

```
Dim objEmail, strFileList, x
strFileList = ""

for each x in fileArray
    strFileList = strFileList & x & vbNewLine
next

Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
with objEmail
    .From = "From@email.com"
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""

    .Subject = "List of wrong files"
    .Body = strFileList

    .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = 'you will need to get the code for this from IT'
    .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    .Configuration.Fields.Update
end with
objEmail.Send
```

Answer (score 1):

I have wrapped the functionality of FileSystemWatcher into a module and provided a small sample of how that can be used for your requirements.

```
# Module FileSystemWatcher

<#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Register to receive filesystemwatcher events for a file or folder.
#>

function Register-FileSystemEvent
{
    [CmdLetBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="File")]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ParameterSetName="File")]
        [string]$path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ParameterSetName="Folder")]
        [string]$folder,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=1,ParameterSetName="Folder")]
        [string]$filter="*.*",
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)]
        [string]$event,
        [scriptblock]$action={
            # Action code here
            $sourceidentifier = $Event.SourceIdentifier
            $FileName = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            $EventType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
            $EventTime = $Event.TimeGenerated
            $message = ("File {0} {1} at {2:yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss}" -f $FileName, $EventType, $EventTime)
            Msg ([environment]::UserName) $message
        },
        $MessageData

    )
    if ($PSCMdLet.ParameterSetName -eq "File")
    {
        $folder = $path.Replace(([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($path)), "")
        $filter = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($path)
    }
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher -ArgumentList $folder, $filter
    $uniqueId = ("{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}" -f [DateTime]::Now)
    $sourceIdentifier = ("File_{0}_{1}" -f $event, $uniqueId)
    $job = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName $event -SourceIdentifier $sourceIdentifier -Action $action -MessageData $MessageData
    $Script:ActiveWatchers += @{$sourceIdentifier = $job}
}

<#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Unregister a FileSystem event or All
    .PARAMETER All
    Unregisters all events
#>
function Unregister-FileSystemEvent
{
    param
    (
        $id,
        [switch]$All
    )
    if ($All.IsPresent)
    {
        foreach ($item in $Script:ActiveWatchers.Keys)
        {
            Unregister-Event $item
            Remove-Job $item
        }
        $Script:ActiveWatchers = @{}
    }
    else
    {
        Unregister-Event $id
        Remove-Job $id
        $Script:ActiveWatchers.Remove($id)
    }

}


function Init
{
    if ($Script:ActiveWatchers.Count -gt 0){Unregister-FileSystemEvent -All}
    $Script:ActiveWatchers = @{}
}

Init

Export-ModuleMember -Function Register-FileSystemEvent, Unregister-FileSystemEvent `
    -Variable ActiveWatchers
```

The basic idea with this module is the ability to specify a scriptblock to be executed once the file event is fired. The -MessageData is used to attach more data to the event once it is fired. In below sample it is used to send the smtpserver and the credentials.

Below the sample code to make use of the fileSystemWatcher module and send an email with the results every time a file is created.

Please note that the arguments to Send-MailMessage might not be exactly what is necessary for your mail server, but is what i used to send the email using office365 server.

```
# Demo using FileSystemWatcher to validate created files

Import-Module .\FileSystemWatcher
$smtpserver = Read-Host -Prompt "Specify your smtp server"
$mailcred = Get-Credential -Message "Specify credentials for your smtp server"

$eventid = Register-FileSystemEvent -folder C:\users\Jower\OneDrive\Documents -event Created -MessageData @{SmtpServer = $smtpserver;Credentials = $mailcred} -action {
    function ValidateFile($filename)
    {
        $messages = @()
        if ([System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($filename) -ne ".xls")
        {
            $messages += ("{0}: Only excel version 97 files allowed here" -f $filename)
        }
        if ([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($filename).Contains(" "))
        {
            $messages += ("{0}: Spaces are not allowed in filename" -f $filename)
        }
        if ($filename.Length -gt 15)
        {
            $messages += ("{0}: Filenames of more than 15 characters is not allowed" -f $filename)
        }
        return $messages
    }
    $smtpserver = $Event.MessageData.SmtpServer
    $credentials = $Event.MessageData.Credentials
    $messages = ValidateFile $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    if ($messages.Count -gt 0)
    {
        Send-MailMessage -From "filealerts@domain.com" -To "recipient@domain.com" -Subject "File validation" -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Body ([string]::Join("`n", $messages)) -port 587 -UseSsl -Credential $credentials
    }
}

# To disable events again.
# Unregister-FileSystemEvent -id $eventid
# Can also use
# Unregister-FileSystemEvent -All
```